# MySQL upgrade from 5.0 to 5.6 on Linux

Tags: mysql, linux

I need to upgrade mysql 5.0 to mysql 5.6 on Linux Server . What are the commands or what are the steps should I follow . I am new to mySQL and Linux. I have gone through the steps to follow but I could not get any complete idea like how to get the software copied to Linux and what are the mysql commands on Linux to upgrade the existing mysql.

Comment: This depends very heavily on your Linux distribution. Some distributions may have packaged the newest MySQL while still officially supporting the older version.

Answer (score 1):

Check the **[Official Documentation on MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading.html)** for the instructions to Upgrade your MySql server.

As @Michael said, It heavily depends on your Linux distro. Generally you can upgrade using **Yum Repository/Apt Repository** via Terminal. You may refer to the documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks Michael & Jatin